# ExtentReports in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having an issue where [ExtentReports](http://extentreports.com/) is not showing the screenshot when the report is viewed on another machine. When saving the image into the report, I pass the absolute path of the image file. The user who wants to view the report have to copy `report.html` and Errorscreenshot folder to their D drive. Then only they can see the screenshot. Please suggest another way so that user can copy these files to any of their location so that screenshot can be viewed.

My code is below:

```
TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

String dest = "D:\\ErrorScreenshots\\"+screenShotName+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
File destination = new File("D:\\ErrorScreenshots\\"+screenShotName+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);    
//FileUtils.copyFile(source, );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative path for your screenshots. Save your screenshots where your html file is located.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relative path. I found it is easier if the image is converted to base64 format. In that case, we only want to share .html file only.

> TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
>
> ```
>     String dest = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
>
>     return "data:image/jpg;base64, " + dest ;
> ```

Comment: yes, its fine but on Jenkins , when I go to the Extent HTML report, thumbnails shows the image but once click on them to zoom, it's blank like below:   https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16231354/41188053-0182fa8e-6b75-11e8-91ac-bcb488024706.jpg. Kindly Suggest

Answer (score 2):

I have used the extent report version 2.40.2 jar and have achieved sharing of my reports folder in this way. The paths are relative here and the report would render correctly with these paths. Hope this helps. I went through many links but nothing actually helped so came up with this logic.

```
public String capture() throws IOException {    
    try{
        //take screenshot and save it in a file
        File sourceFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        //copy the file to the required path
        File destinationFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/reports/image_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".png");
        FileHandler.copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);  
        String[] relatvePath = destinationFile.toString().split("reports");
        screenshotPath = ".\\" + relatvePath[1];
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //if it fails to take screenshot then this block will execute
        System.out.println("Failure to take screenshot "+e);
    }
    return screenshotPath;
}

        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, Constants.REPORT_ERROR, test.addScreenCapture(capture()) + Constants.REPORT_ERROR_STATUS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use relative path for screenshot as below:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\ErrorScreenshots\\"+screenShotName+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
File destination = new File(path);
```

Comment: It worked. I have added like this 
        String dest = ".\\ErrorScreenshots\\"+screenShotName+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
        File destination = new File(".\\ErrorScreenshots\\"+screenShotName+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");